# plus one button not loading when html5 offline storage is enabled

Tags: html, google-plus-one, offline-mode

I added the following plus one script at the top of the head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
```

and then added plus one button in the page with below code

```
<g:plusone size="tall"></g:plusone>
```

Under normal conditions everything works fine. But when I enable offline storage with the following:

```
<html manifest="./offline.appcache">
```

the plus one button is not getting loaded(except for the first time). On checking the console it shows:
Failed to load resource http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js

I tried adding the following in NETWORK section of my offline cache manifest:

```
http://apis.google.com/js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding the wildcard '*' to the NETWORK section of the cache manifest solved the issue.